# Bitwise shift returns unexpected value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm performing `55 << 30` in C# and Python 3. C# returns `-1073741824`, which is what I want, but Python returns `59055800320`. Can someone explain why exactly this happens, and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python ints are arbitrarily large ... you can force it sort of

```
import numpy

numpy.int32(55) << 30
```

Answer (score 1):

Python integers are unbounded, so `59055800320` is the correct answer, but to simulate C#'s 32-bit limitation on integers and 2s complement negative numbers, you can do the math:

```
>>> hex(55)
'0x37'
>>> hex(55 << 30)  # 36-bit result, too large for 32-bit integers
'0xdc0000000'
>>> hex(55 << 30 & 0xffffffff) # mask off lower 32 bits.
'0xc0000000'
>>> ((55 << 30) & 0xffffffff)  # but the sign (bit 31) is a one, so it should be negative
3221225472
```

Bit 31 in a 32-bit signed integer has value -2<sup>31</sup>, but unsigned it has value 2<sup>31</sup>, meaning the value is 2<sup>32</sup> too high, so:

```
>>> ((55 << 30) & 0xffffffff) - (1<<32)
-1073741824
```

Here's a function:

```
def signed_32bit_shift_left(n,s):
    tmp = (n << s) & 0xffffffff
    return tmp - (1<<32) if tmp & 0x80000000 else tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, Python `int`s are much larger than you might expect.  To observe this (Python 3.7.4):

```
>>> import sys
>>> type(55)
<class 'int'>
>>> sys.getsizeof(int())
24
```

[`sys.getsizeof()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) will return the size, in bytes, of an object in memory.